# Can a vector be the value of a wave functional?

Tags: wavefunction, field-theory

I know that the wavefunction values ​​of a quantum field are complex numbers. I know that the square of these numbers tells us the probability that the configuration to which this complex number is assigned will occur. I want to ask if pairs of complex numbers (vectors) can also be assigned to individual configurations of the quantum field? Thanks

Comment: A probability amplitude is always a complex number, so the wavefunctional outputs a complex number. However, the input field is not necessarily scalar and can be vector valued.

Comment: What if we have two quantum fields that are in superposition? What if I don't know if the configuration that results from the collapse is a function that moves right or left? Isn't it similar to a spin that can be up or down?

Comment: I think of it as a superposition of two vectors multiplied by two complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, it’s just a matter of bookkeeping. Your spin 1/2 can be seen as a wavefunction taking into argument a binary variable.

Comment: How would you combine those two fields? Does this mean that every function that moves to the right is in superposition with some function that moves to the left? Are they pairs of functions that have the same energy but opposite momentum?

Comment: I  have found this sentence on the internet. Does this mean that the value of a wave function can be a vector? "For example, the wave function could be a vector at each point, so rotation of the system could rotate this vector as well as moving it to a different r."